# Suggestion required for building microservices architecture

Tags: java, spring-boot, architecture, microservices, system-design

I have a requirement of building a web app, which is more like a system that will have inventory and sell the items.
There is no need for a payment gateway as it is an over-the-counter system and payment integration is not required for it.

I have the following:

- user service: That manages users
- inventory service: that manages inventory
- order service: that takes orders and processes them

Each service has its own separate database.

Inventory and order service will communicate often as order processing will need inventory updates.
Now, the question is,
How do I manage this situation? because I need to manage the inventory, keep the order history and have it in a way that order history can be seen, for reports like sales of specific items, etc.

The problem I foresee is if order-service will have its own DB and inventory will have its own DB. for the purpose of fetching reports, it will also require calls to inventory-service for getting the item details. ( I am assuming that I will save inventory-item-id in order-service DB)

Can you please suggest proper way to deal with this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is using microservices a requirement? How big your team is? How many transactions at peak hours do you anticipate?

Comment: You could take a look at event driven design which is often used for microservice architectures. Communication between microservices is typically handled through choreography or orchestration. Lots of articles and samples exist on the web on this topic... What to choose is use case dependent (as always ;-) )